# Regex pattern for a text with carriage returns in xml

Tags: regex, xml, carriage-return

In a xml file I want to change the content so that the columnnames become tags instead of attributes.

```
<column name="bla">some text</column>
```

Should become:

```
<bla>some text</bla>
```

I got this partialy working with the following regex:

```
regex:        <column name="(.*)">(.*)<\/column>
substitution: <$1>$2</$1>
```

but when the text contains carriage returns, this is not suffictient. Adding [\r\n]* only helps partialy as well. Any ideas on this?

It shoud work on this:

```
<column name="bla">some text</column>
<column name="bla">some text
</column>
<column name="bla">some text
        </column>
<column name="bla">some text
some text</column>
<column name="bla">some text
some text
some text</column>
```

To become:

```
<bla>some text</bla>
<bla>some text
</bla>
<bla>some text
        </bla>
<bla>some text
some text</bla>
<bla>some text
some text
some text</bla>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise you to use an xml parser to do this job or to create an [XSLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) stylesheet to spare time and problems in the future (write the language you're using to do this job so we can recommend you something).

Anyway your regex does not work cause the dot `.` need the DOTALL modifier `(?s)` to match (newline/carriage return also).

```
<column\s+name="([^"]+)"\s*>(.*?)<\/column>
```

The lazy modifier `?` after `.*` is also required: if missing the regex `(.*?)` matches everything from the first opening tag `<column>` to the last closing tag `</column>`.

Try the regex online [here](https://regex101.com/r/fP2kW3/3)

**UPDATE** - PHP

```
$pattern = '~(?s)<column\s+name="([^"]+)"\s*>(.*?)<\/column>~';
$text = "<column name=\"bla\">some text</column>\n<column name=\"bla\">some text\n</column>\n<column name=\"bla\">some text\n        </column>\n<column name=\"bla\">some text\nsome text</column>\n<column name=\"bla\">some text\nsome text\nsome text</column>";

$result = preg_replace($pattern, "<$1>$2</$1>", $text);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works indeed in the online editor, but fails when I use it in PHP. Any idea why that is? I use it with $pattern = '~<column\s+name="([^"]+)"\s*>(.*?)<\/column>~'; preg_replace($pattern, "<$1>$2</$1>", $text); It fails on the given example.

Comment: @Aak: i've updated again using your $pattern string, simply the dotall modifier ``(?s)`` is missing.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot @GsusRecovery. Part of my goal was to use this issue to learn a bit more about regex. Thanks to you I did, i had never heard about the dotall. Now I do. For others, see here for some explanation: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-modifiers.html